# Semantic significance of <li> without <ol> or <ul>?

Tags: html, list, semantics, listitem

My site's h1 is also the "home" link, so obviously I put it within the nav tag. The other links in the nav were originally put in an unordered list, like this:

```
    <nav>
      <h1><a href="#" class="active">Site Name</a></h1>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a>
         <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a>
         <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```

Standard, right? As you can imagine, on subpages, the nav stays the same but the "active" class gets applied to the relavent Nav Item.

Here's the problem. At mobile screen widths, the nav compresses into a dropdown menu where the "active" link is the only link shown above the drop. That's fine on the homepage where the h1 is the active link, but it seems like my CSS is going to get super messy on subpages.

I've been noticing that some well respected frontend developers use list items free of ordered/unordered lists. These are folks who hold semantics in high esteem, so it made me wonder they might be thinking...

So I'm stuck. It seems wrong to put my h1 in the ul, but this also seems wrong:

```
    <nav>
      <li><h1><a href="#" class="active">Site Name</a></h1></li>
      <li><a href="">Nav Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Nav Item 1</a></li>
    </nav>
```

I know that I can get the LOOK of what I want to achieve almost any way I markup the HTML, but I'd like to do it as semantically as possible while avoiding a CSS/JS nightmare / or any hacks.

Comment: " some well respected frontend developers use list items free of ordered/unordered lists". Care to share who you're referring to?

Comment: ...and just because others do it... doesn't make it correct...

Comment: Why would it not be correct? Other than validation. I'm curious about the semantics.

Comment: IMHO each LI item is a "[L]ist[I]tem" and a ListItem has a dependent relationship on a List.  Semantically a list can either be ordered or unordered and HTML provides an option for each OL + UL.  Considering as a developer I often want a parent element to style the entire list the OL/UL makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The standard is clear](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html) :

> Permitted parent elements :
>
> ul, ol, menu

Any other use should be avoided as a browser might very well not support it.

The fact the norm prohibits it means there is no accepted semantic, apart the one each developer invents for his own use.

Comment: As it's not valid there is no accepted or normalized semantic... only the one each developer invent for his own use.

Comment: True. Decided to go against invention and w/ convention. Now using `<nav><menu><li><a><h1>..</a></li><li>...` etc. I don't want to specify whether it's an ordered or unordered list. Could be either/or. It's a menu of options. Their order (or lack thereof) is incidental.